# How to get video chunks with Axios

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios, nodejs-stream

So far I have the backend on nodejs which gives me the video I request by chunks.
I've been trying to get the video url and place it into a video tag using axios and responseType as blob, sending a range header.
This is the axios code:

```
await stream.get(videoUrl,{responseType: 'blob', adapter: httpAdapter}).then(res=>{
                var video = document.querySelector('video')
                video.scr = URL.createObjectURL(res.data)
                this.open = true
                this.$store.dispatch('isLoading', false)
            })
```

I get this request header:
Content-Range: bytes 0-1000/284219714

The thing is, it doesn't play the video, it get's stuck on the first asked chunk.

Any ideas?